# Oozie failed to run Spark2 action

Tags: oozie, apache-spark-2.0

Using Ambari 2.6, HDP-2.6.4

I followed [guide](https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.6.0/bk_spark-component-guide/content/ch_oozie-spark-action.html#spark-config-oozie-spark2) to create a spark2 share lib, and remove duplicated jar from spark2 and oozie folders, but still got the following error:

sometimes:

```
2018-03-23 11:36:55,071 ERROR [AsyncDispatcher event handler] org.apache.hadoop.yarn.event.AsyncDispatcher: Error in dispatcher thread
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.util.StringUtils.toLowerCase(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.util.MRApps.addToClasspathIfNotJar(MRApps.java:332)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.util.MRApps.addClasspathToEnv(MRApps.java:300)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.util.MRApps.setClasspath(MRApps.java:261)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.job.impl.TaskAttemptImpl.getInitialClasspath(TaskAttemptImpl.java:621)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.job.impl.TaskAttemptImpl.createCommonContainerLaunchContext(TaskAttemptImpl.java:757)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.job.impl.TaskAttemptImpl.createContainerLaunchContext(TaskAttemptImpl.java:821)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.job.impl.TaskAttemptImpl$ContainerAssignedTransition.transition(TaskAttemptImpl.java:1551)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.job.impl.TaskAttemptImpl$ContainerAssignedTransition.transition(TaskAttemptImpl.java:1528)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.state.StateMachineFactory$SingleInternalArc.doTransition(StateMachineFactory.java:362)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.state.StateMachineFactory.doTransition(StateMachineFactory.java:302)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.state.StateMachineFactory.access$300(StateMachineFactory.java:46)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.state.StateMachineFactory$InternalStateMachine.doTransition(StateMachineFactory.java:448)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.job.impl.TaskAttemptImpl.handle(TaskAttemptImpl.java:1078)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.job.impl.TaskAttemptImpl.handle(TaskAttemptImpl.java:145)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster$TaskAttemptEventDispatcher.handle(MRAppMaster.java:1311)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster$TaskAttemptEventDispatcher.handle(MRAppMaster.java:1303)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.event.AsyncDispatcher.dispatch(AsyncDispatcher.java:183)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.event.AsyncDispatcher$1.run(AsyncDispatcher.java:110)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2018-03-23 11:36:55,075 INFO [AsyncDispatcher ShutDown handler] org.apache.hadoop.yarn.event.AsyncDispatcher: Exiting, bbye.
```

sometimes:

```
2018-03-23 10:51:31,570 ERROR [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster: Error starting MRAppMaster
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.CryptoUtils.isEncryptedSpillEnabled(Lorg/apache/hadoop/conf/Configuration;)Z
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster.initJobCredentialsAndUGI(MRAppMaster.java:735)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster.serviceInit(MRAppMaster.java:264)
    at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.init(AbstractService.java:163)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster$5.run(MRAppMaster.java:1598)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1869)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster.initAndStartAppMaster(MRAppMaster.java:1595)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster.main(MRAppMaster.java:1526)
2018-03-23 10:51:31,573 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.util.ExitUtil: Exiting with status 1
```

Answer (score 1):

I just found it, it's my fault, I packed hadoop and hive jars with my application, which version is different with the hadoop system.